# Display ckeditor in django without form.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, ckeditor

I am trying to build an application in which I want to add a rich text editor. I have added CKEditor and it is working fine on the admin panel. I want to know if there is any way to display the editor without `form.py`, just to save data from simple post requests.

this is how it is looking but it should be the rich text editor.
[image]

is there any alternative way except forms.py for adding that editor?
Thank You in advance :)

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField 

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    previous_work = RichTextField(max_length=2000)
    skills = RichTextField(max_length=2000)
```

html

```
    <form class="container">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.media }}
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label class="form-label">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Previous Work</label>
                <!-- <input type="number" class="form-control" name="summary" id="summary"> -->
                <textarea name="Previous_work" class="form-control" id="Previous_work" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Skills</label>
                <!-- <input type="number" class="form-control" name="summary" id="summary"> -->
                <textarea name="skills" class="form-control" id="skills" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: Please provide more details eg. code, error (if any)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari there are no errors, I will modify it with code, it might help you

Comment: use it directly in `views.py`

Comment: @mirodil yes but other fields are being reflected correctly only my 2 fields of CKeditors are not being shown in the editor how can I do it using ```views.py```

Comment: @GauravKulkarni try to add `{{ form.as_p }}`

Comment: @mirodil added but no change in the display.

Answer (score 0):

#### Do just like this...

##### ----- models.py -------

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
class CKModel(models.Model):
    c = RichTextField()
```

##### ------ views.py --------

```
def CKView(request):
    form = CKForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c= request.POST.get('skills')
        CKModel(c=c).save()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})
```

##### ------- in HTML Code -----------

```
{% block body %}
     <form action="" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form.media}}
          <textarea name="skills" class="form-control"  id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

          <button type="submit">add</button>
     </form>

{% endblock body %}
```

##### ------ Webpage Output ------

[image]

##### After saved in django admin panel

[image]

Comment: from where did CKForm come? it is showing me that it is not defined